# Vertical text in Razor View

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I Have the following view:

```
@model YFA.ViewModels.YoungFFSkillVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Training for Drill";
}
<div class="row">
    <h2>Training for Drill on @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DrillDate)</h2>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DrillId)
    <div class="form-group">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    @foreach (var skill in Model.SkillList)
                    {
                        <th class="rotate"><span class="intact">@skill</span></th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.YoungFFs.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.YoungFFs[i].ID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.YoungFFs[i].Name)
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.YoungFFs[i].Name)
                        </td>
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.YoungFFs[i].Skills.Count; j++)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.YoungFFs[i].Skills[j].ID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.YoungFFs[i].Skills[j].YoungFFId)
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.YoungFFs[i].Skills[j].IsSelected)
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

With the following in the Site css:

```
th.rotate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    -o-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    transform-origin: 65px 60px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    /*height:30px;*/
    /*float:left;*/
    /*width:30px;*/
}

span.intact {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    height:150px;
}
```

However I get the following view displayed:

[image]

Names have been blanked out on purpose.

As you can see the top row which is vertical to allow a better layout is chopped off and also over the title.

How can I adjust the view or css to stop this?

Comment: It sounds like you need `.row > h2 { margin-top: 50px }`, or something similar.

Comment: @ObsidianAge where would this need to be?

Comment: ...in the CSS. That **should** shift the table further down the page, so that `Mounting And Dismounting` doesn't overlap with the title :) The offset can of course be changed. There's probably also the possibility of using `word-wrap` to cover *really* long titles, but you'd probably need to show the HTML **output** rather than the Razor, in order to work out exactly how that should be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, thats sorted it however I have to adjust the margin if I add another category thats longer again, is there anyway of doing this dynamically?

Comment: You can't (easily) adjust the margin of one element based on the length of another. The best bet would to be using `word-wrap: break-word;` in combination with a set width on the same element. That **looks** like `tr td:nth-of-type(2)` to me from your code, but it's difficult to tell because of you posting Razor code rather than HTML, and also not having any class names. I'd recommend using class names (especially for the skills row), and targeting it directly :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of `th.rotate` to something all the text will fit in.

```
th.rotate {
    white-space: nowrap;    
    height: 275px;
}

th.rotate > .intact {
    transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 30px;
}
```

Here's [a working Bootstrap sample](http://www.bootply.com/bUqathAmf4).  I also set the table's `border="1"` so you can see the effect in the sample and used `<div>` instead of `<span>`.

Comment: Is there any way of making this dynamic so if the name is longer the gap stays the same?

Comment: Yes, if the columns are dynamic and you don't know their length ahead of time, you could write some JavaScript to figure out what that `th.rotate` height ought to be and push that value into a style on the `<th>` elements.